# using JSON how to pass data from table view to section view on iphone

Tags: iphone

i have all that data with me in tableview but when i dont know how to transfer these values on section view when user press any cell

this is how i am getting values
[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"number"];

now how to  transfer these values to section

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";







   cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil ) {

        NSLog(@" inside");
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];



        mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 5.0, 220.0, 15.0)] autorelease];

        mainLabel.tag =33;

        //  mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        [mainLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]]];

        mainLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

        mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        mainLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        //mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];
        mainLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


    }
//  NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //[cell setData:itemAtIndex];

    mainLabel.text = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"number"];
    NSLog(@" dicst 5@",stream);
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
                return cell;

}






- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller
            NSLog(@" push");

//**[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"number"];**  how to do this so i can access from section view 

            aDetail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];



            [self.navigationController pushViewController:aDetail animated:YES];

            [aDetail release];


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a property on your `DetailViewController` to hold the data, and pass it to that before pushing the view controller onto the navigation stack. Equivalently, add an extra parameter to the view controller's constructor. So given:

```
id detail = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"number"];
```

either do:

```
aDetail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
aDetail.dataObject = detail;
```

or:

```
aDetail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] dataObject: detail];
```

Then you can access your data from within the detail view controller. To add this property, you can do this:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
{
  //...
  id dataObject;
}
//...
@property (nonatomic, retain) id dataObject;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize dataObject;
//...
@end
```

This means that your `DetailViewController` now has API for being told about the object it's representing.

Comment: but jsonArray is defined in tableview not in detailview  so i cant access from detailview can you explain more about id detail?? you mean in detailViewController--> viewdidLoad() i have to define id ??

Comment: Yes thats working perfectly fine but my dataObject is having these values {
    home = sdfsdfdsf;
    number = "212 555-1234";
    type = home;
}
 so how to catch each of them like dataObject.number or so in section view so that i can display them in different cells ??

Answer (score 0):

to Access indivudal item you can do something like this for those who might want this

```
jsonItem=dataObject;// where jsonItem is a NSDict
    NSLog(@" v %@",jsonItem);// all data


    jsonLabel.text = [jsonItem objectForKey:@"type"];// this is how you can display them
```

thanks